# RX 580 8GB not using more than 2GB memory

Tags: amd-graphics, v-ram

My AMD RX 580 does not use all its memory (8GB) but only up to 2GB what could possibly be wrong?

I use ubuntu 17.10 with the latest kernel (4.13)

my GPU shows up as Radeon RX 580 Series (POLARIS10 / DRM 3.18.0 / 4.13.0-18-generic, LLVM 5.0.0) on the overview (I have mesa 17.3 )

Benchmarks see only 256 to 2560 MB

when entering

```
echo $"VRAM: "$(($(grep -P -o -i "(?<=memory:).*(?=kbytes)" /var/log/Xorg.0.log) / 1024))$" Mb"
```

I get `VRAM: 2048 Mb` back

When entering `grep -i memory /var/log/Xorg.0.log`

I get

```
[    34.272] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 2097152 kBytes
[    34.302] (II) NVIDIA: Using 6144.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
[    34.405] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
```

When entering `LC_ALL=C lspci -v | grep -EA10 "3D|VGA" | grep 'prefetchable'`

I get

```
Memory at feb06000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]
Memory at fea00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
```

When entering   `sudo lshw -class display`

I get

```
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: e7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:30 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fea00000-fea3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

Yet I dont get it :P